# Central limit theorem, how many tosses, accurate probability

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

We have a credible information that a certain coin isn't symmetric. That is, the probability that we get tails is less than $0.3$.

How many tosses do we need to establish with $0.95$ certainty that the results we get will let us calculate the probability of getting tails with $0.99$ accuracy?

Here is my approach:

$p \le 0.3$ is the probability of getting tails after each toss

$X(\omega)=X_1(\omega) + ... + X_n(\omega)$ number of tails we get after $n$ tosses

$n$ is the number of tosses which we want to calculate

But I don't know how to write down the proper inequality in which I will use $0.99$ and $0.95$ which will help me calculate it.

I mean, what random variable do I need to estimate here?

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Do you mean with $0.99$ accuracy?

Comment: Why are the decimals replaced by commas?

Comment: You're right. $0.99$ makes more sense. I'll correct my question.